XMLRPC Server connecting to end-devices outside of its own network
I'm trying to make a server which I can address from outside of its own network so I'm trying to work with public IP addresses. However when I try to connect them I get an error:

ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] A connection could not be established because the target computer refused to connect.

Here's my code:
Server (I use the private IP address here because otherwise there is an Error OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is invalid in this context):
class RequestHandler(SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler):
    rpc_paths = ('/RPC2',)

with SimpleXMLRPCServer(('172.30.1.217', 8000),allow_none=True,
                        requestHandler=RequestHandler) as server:
    server.register_introspection_functions()

    # Register pow() function; this will use the value of
    # pow.__name__ as the name, which is just 'pow'.
    server.register_function(pow)

    # Register a function under a different name
    def adder_function(x, y):
        return x + y
    server.register_function(adder_function, 'add')

    # Register an instance; all the methods of the instance are
    # published as XML-RPC methods (in this case, just 'mul').
    class MyFuncs:
        def mul(self, x, y):
            return x * y

        def message(self,message,sender):
            with open('chat.txt','a') as file:
                file.write(sender+": "+message+"\n")

        def openchat(self):
            with open('chat.txt','r') as file:
                s=""
                for line in file:
                    s+=line.strip()+"\n"
            return s

        def clear(self,partly=True):
            s=[]
            with open('chat.txt','r') as file:
                for line in file:
                    s.append(line.strip())
            if partly:
                with open('chat.txt','w') as file:
                    file.write(s[len(s)-2]+"\n"+s[len(s)-1]+"\n")
            else:
                with open('chat.txt','w') as file:
                    file.write("")
                    
        def getchatlength(self):
            with open('chat.txt','r') as file:
                i=0
                for line in file:
                    i+=1
            return i
    server.register_instance(MyFuncs())

    # Run the server's main loop
    server.serve_forever()

Client:
import xmlrpc.client
import tkinter.messagebox as tk
import os.path as o
import select
import sys
import keyboard
import time
from playsound3 import playsound

def loadlength():
    with open("infoChat.txt","r") as f:
        for line in f:
            return int(line)

def inclength():
    länge=loadlength()+1
    with open("infoChat.txt","w") as f:
        f.write(str(länge))

def writelength(length):
    with open("infoChat.txt","w") as f:
        f.write(str(length))

s = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('http://178.190.81.229:8000')
if o.isfile("infoChat.txt")==False:
    with open("infoChat.txt","w") as f:
        length=s.getchatlength()
        if length>0:
            print("Neue Nachricht")
            playsound('audio.mp3')
        f.write(str(length))
while True:
    länge = loadlength()
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('alt'):
            break
        time.sleep(0.01)
        if länge<s.getchatlength():
            print("Neue Nachricht")
            playsound('audio.mp3')
            inclength()
            länge = loadlength()
    time.sleep(1)
    i=int(input("m=0;o=1;c=2\n"))
    match i:
        case 0:
            m=input("Nachricht:\n")
            s.message(m,"Yannick")
            inclength()
        case 1:
            chat=s.openchat()
            print(chat)
            #tk.showinfo(title="Chat",message=chat)
        case 2:
            s.clear()
            writelength(2)
        case 3:
            s.clear(False)
            writelength(0)
        case _:
            print("nicht mal das kannst du")

I've tried to find solutions but I don't find any in the internet
